Problems with React Native Google Sign-in With Passport in NodeJS API
I have a NodeJS API that handle user authentication with username/password and google. Both work perfect on web browser or postman, but i cant make it work in react native.
Here's the code that handle the Login in API:
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
const User = require('../models/User')
const register = require(`../services/auth/register`)
const {
  google: { clientId, clientSecret }
} = require('../../config')

module.exports = function(passport) {
  // google auth
  passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy(
      {
        clientID: clientId,
        clientSecret,
        callbackURL: '/auth/google/callback'
      },
      async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        try {
          let user = await User.findOne({ $or: [
            { email: profile.emails[0].value },
            { google_id:  }
          ] })

          if (user) {
            return done(null, user)
          } else {
            const response = await register({
              name: profile.displayName.split(` `).join(``),
              google_id: ,
              email: profile.emails[0].value,
              profile_picture: profile.photos[0].value
            })

            done(null, response.user)
          }
        } catch (err) {
          done(err, false)
        }
      }
    )
  )

  // Local Auth
  passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'name',
        passwordField: 'password'
      }, async (email, password, done) => {
        try {
          /*
            All the validations are done at the Middleware
          */
         
          const user = await User.findOne({ $or: [
            { name: email },
            { email }
          ] })

          if (!user)
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Email ou senha incorretos' })

          return done(null, user)
        } catch (error) {
          return done(error)
        }
    })
  )

  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id)
  })

  passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
    try {
      const user = await User.findById(id)
      done(null, user)
    } catch (err) {
      done(err, null)
    }
  })
}profile.idprofile.id

Here are the API routes (just in case):
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const passport = require('passport')
const passportConfig = require('../api/config/passportAuth')
const {
    register,
    userData,
    confirmEmail,
    forgetPassword,
    resetPassword
} = require('../api/controllers/authController')

// Middlewares
const userRegisterValidation = require('../middlewares/validations/auth/userRegisterValidation')
const userLoginValidation = require('../middlewares/validations/auth/userLoginValidation')
const checkTokenMW = require('../middlewares/checkTokenMW')

passportConfig(passport)

// Routes
router.post("/register", userRegisterValidation, register)
router.get("/confirm_email", confirmEmail)
router.post('/forget-password', forgetPassword)
router.post('/reset-password', resetPassword)
router.get('/user', checkTokenMW, userData)

// passport
router.post('/login', userLoginValidation, passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/auth/user',
    failureRedirect: '/',
    failureFlash: true 
}))

router.get('/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile', 'email'] }))
router.get('/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google', {
    successRedirect: '/auth/user',
    failureRedirect: '/',
    failureFlash: true
}))

router.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
    try {
        req.logout(err => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(`error`)
                return
            }
    
            console.log(`deslogado`)
            res.redirect('/')
        })
    } catch {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: `nao tem nenhum usuario logado` })
    }
})

module.exports = router

And on the React Native: heres the login page code:
import {
StyleSheet,
Text,
View,
TextInput,
Button,
Pressable,
} from "react-native"
import { useState } from "react"
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux"
import \* as SecureStore from "expo-secure-store"
import axios from "axios"

export default function Login({ navigation }: any) {
const dispatch = useDispatch()
const \[form, setForm\] = useState({ name: "", password: "" })
const \[loading, setLoading\] = useState(false)
const \[errMsg, setErrMsg\] = useState("")

const handleForm = async () =\> {
setLoading(true)
try {
const response = await axios.post(
"http://192.168.1.174:3000/auth/login",
form
)

      dispatch({
        type: "user",
        payload: {
          name: response.data.user.name,
          id: response.data.user._id,
          pfp: response.data.user.profile_picture,
        },
      })
    } catch (err: any) {
      setErrMsg(err.response.data.message || "Error calling API")
    }
    setLoading(false)

}

// Google auth url: http://192.168.1.174:3000/auth/google, callback: http://192.168.1.174:3000/auth/google/callback

return (
\<View style={styles.container}\>
\<View\>
\<Text style={styles.title}\>Login\</Text\>

        <Text style={styles.label}>Username:</Text>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="username"
          onChangeText={(text) => setForm({ ...form, name: text })}
        />
    
        <Text style={styles.label}>Password:</Text>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="password"
          onChangeText={(text) => setForm({ ...form, password: text })}
        />
    
        <Button title="Send" onPress={() => handleForm()} disabled={loading} />
    
        {errMsg ? <Text style={styles.label}>{errMsg}</Text> : <View />}
    
        <Pressable
          style={styles.pressableLink}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ForgetPassword")}
        >
          <Text style={styles.link}>Esqueceu a senha?</Text>
        </Pressable>
    
        <Text>Or</Text>
      </View>
    </View>

)
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1,
backgroundColor: "#fff",
alignItems: "center",
justifyContent: "center",
},
title: {
fontSize: 22,
fontWeight: "bold",
},
label: {
fontSize: 10,
},
link: {
fontSize: 10,
color: "blue",
},
pressableLink: {
alignItems: "center",
justifyContent: "center",
marginTop: 5,
},
})

The username/password auth is working, but i dont know how to do the Google login there. The logic is: you call the /auth/google, you do the login with your google account in the browser, and it return you your data (/auth/user redirect in API is a route that returns the data of the logged user)
Can someone help me?
